# SonanQube Docker Container won't start due to backelite jar. How to remove it?

Tags: docker, sonarqube, docker-compose

I installed a backelite-sonar-swift-plugin.jar and because of it my sonarqube docker container won't start anymore. I cannot docker exec because the container won't start so is there a way to delete the file without starting it?

I am using [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/blob/master/recipes.md) to run my containers and i've tried removing the sonarqube container and images but when i docker-compose up although they will download the sonarqube image again but when starting the container it the backelite-sonar-swift-plugin.jar is in there. Why is it in there? Doesn't it suppose to be gone cause a new image has been downloaded already?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the image is using already cached data or existing volumes from previous container. Remove previous volumes too along with removing the container. If you wanna see how volumes are removed, you will have to look for it yourself, since I know of removing all volumes of all container and removing individual volumes can be done by using `docker volume ls` and `docker volume rm`. I prefer removing all docker volumes by:

`docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)`

And if this does not helps, then please provide the errors which are shown before the container exits.